# Efficient matrix times column vector for each column

Tags: intel-mkl

I have a matrix

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

that I need to multiply with a column vector

```
[2
 3
 4]
```

to get

```
2 4 6
3 6 9
4 8 12
```

Now, I can make the vector into a matrix and do an element-wise multiplication, but is there also an efficient way to do this in MKL / CBLAS?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the information provided below if it helps depending on your requirement.

For vector-vector operations, please refer the below link.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-1-routines-and-functions.html#blas-level-1-routines-and-functions

For matrix-vector operations, please refer the below link.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-2-routines.html#blas-level-2-routines
l
For matrix-matrixoperations, please refer the below link.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-3-routines.html#blas-level-3-routines

The question mark in the group name corresponds to different character codes indicating the data type (s, d, c, and z or their combination)

Comment: I had done that. I currently use a loop over all rows with dscal, but it is a bit ugly. I was wondering it could be done in one elegant and fast way.